# Magento upgrade error

Tags: magento, ssh, pear

I'm trying to upgrade my Magento setup via SSH, I'm trying to run the ./pear mage-setup command and getting the following error:

```
-bash: ./pear: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to fix this error?

I can't upgrade through connect so I'm wondering if it is at all possible to upgrade by copying the files across manually from a zip of the latest version?

Comment: what version of Magento are you trying to update from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from v1.5.0.1, `pear` has been replace by `mage`.
So you should try:

```
./mage mage-setup
```

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a bad character in the mage-setup script - there shouldn't be a ^M in there - try removing it and running the script again.

And yes, you can just download the upgrade files and copy them over, just be careful not overwrite any changes you may have made to the code base...

Comment: Where's the mage-setup script held?

Comment: Depends on where you installed it - you might be able to do a: `which mage-setup` to show you the location.

Comment: It's installed in the root directory of my server. I was trying to run the SSH command ./pear mage-setup when I came across the error

Comment: Like dbcn mentioned, `nano ./pear` or grab the file again from an archive of the same version as you're running and make sure it's uploaded properly, most likely carriage return issues.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you transferred your Magento setup from a Windows environment to a *nix one. Run dos2linux on them and it should be fine.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/ lists other ways of converting your text files over.